# String splitting with a stop character in R

Tags: r

My data is as follows:
“Louis Hamilton”
“Tiger Wolf”
“Sachin Tendulkar”
“Lebron James”
“Michael Shoemaker”
“Hollywood – Career as an Actor”

- I need to extract all the characters until a space or a dash(-) is reached
- I need to extract no more than 10 characters

My desired output is
“Louis”
“Tiger”
“Sachin”
“Lebron”
“Michael”
“Hollywood”

I tried using below function, but it didn’t work

```
Sportstars<-function(charvec)
{min.length < 10, (x, hyph.pattern = Null)}
```

Can anyone help, please?

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub`

```
sub("^([^- ]+).*", "\\1", v1)
#[1] "Louis"     "Tiger"     "Sachin"    "Lebron"    "Michael"   "Hollywood"
```

Or another version with the length condition as well

```
grep("^.{1,10}$", sub("\\s+.*", "", v1), value = TRUE)
#[1] "Louis"     "Tiger"     "Sachin"    "Lebron"    "Michael"   "Hollywood"
```

---

Or with `word` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
word(v1, 1)
#[1] "Louis"     "Tiger"     "Sachin"    "Lebron"    "Michael"   "Hollywood"
```

Also, if we need to implement the last condition as well

```
sapply(strsplit(v1, "[– -]"), function(x) {
    x1 <- setdiff(x, "")
     x1[1][nchar(x1[1]) < 10]})
#[1] "Louis"     "Tiger"     "Sachin"    "Lebron"    "Michael"   "Hollywood"
```

#### data

```
v1 <- c( "Louis Hamilton", "Tiger Wolf", "Sachin Tendulkar", 
  "Lebron James", "Michael Shoemaker", "Hollywood – Career as an Actor")
```